# Change "read more" link in Joomla! 3.1.5 Stable?

Tags: joomla

I am using joomla 3.1.5 for my blog. Want to change the link for "read more" in article.

1. Currently its showing something like "mysite.com/index.php/alias name"
2. I want to change this to "mysite.com/index.php/category name/alias name".

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why would you want to add an extra forward slash to the URL?

Comment: oh. sorry its a typo error.

Answer (score 1):

readmore-links are created using the router - functionality (  JRoute::_('...') ) of joomla. It is up to the component how this is handled. 
For com_content this is defined in 
/components/com_content/router.php

It might be possible to change the output of the router by following the recipie here: 
[Router Plugins](http://docs.joomla.org/Router_Plugins)

...but I have not tried this myself,

regards JOnas